# In what ways do you make use of C# Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, lambda

Pour in your posts. I'll start with a couple, let us see how much we can collect.

To provide inline event handlers like

```
button.Click += (sender,args) =>
{
};
```

To find items in a collection

```
 var dogs= animals.Where(animal => animal.Type == "dog");
```

For iterating a collection, like

```
 animals.ForEach(animal=>Console.WriteLine(animal.Name));
```

Let them come!!

Comment: Doesn't SO have enough pointless "questions" already? How about asking how people make use of "if" statements? Or classes? int's, maybe? Lambdas are just a handy new feature in the language, on par with every other feature of the language. Do we need these rep-whoring questions all the time?

Comment: Jalf, I myself went through the code and wrote, and found that I'm using Lambdas in various interesting ways - compared to Ifs and whiles, Lambda is a much more powerful feature. Hence, I thought this post will help myself and others to learn more usages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning an custom object:

```
var dude = mySource.Select(x => new {Name = x.name, Surname = x.surname});
```

Comment: Did you know, you can just do  new {x.name, x.surname} ? The properties will be lowercase as in this example.

Answer (score 2):

One line function

```
Func<int, int> multiply = x => x * 2;
int y = multiply(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different one - you can use them [(like this)](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/f44dc57a9dc5168d/02c312dcf8a9a769#4805324df6b30218) to simulate the missing "infoof"/"nameof" operators in C# - i.e. so that instead of hard-coding to a property name as a string, you can use a lambda. This means that it is validated at compile time (which strings can't be).

There is obviously a performance cost to this, hence "just for fun", but interesting...

Answer (score 1):

With method invoker to update UI from a multi threaded componenet event

```
void Task_Progress(object sender,TaskProgressArgs  e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateProgress(e)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating an accumulator.

```
    static Func<int, int> Foo(int n)
    {
        return a => n += a;
    }
```

Note the closure usage here.  it's creating an accumulator that "remembers" the value of n between calls - without a class or instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

For aggregate operations with Linq:

```
public Double GetLengthOfElements(string[] wordArr) {

   double count = wordArr.Sum(word => word.Length);
   return count;
}
```

Sure beats using foreach

Answer (score -1):

To express an unnamed function.

Comment: @DaveZych - okay, maybe I'll do that, four years later.

Comment: You can delete the answer... I got here by the tools as well...

Comment: @DaveZych. Unfortunately this does answer the question. this is why I flagged the question for deletion...